# Hiding a row in table using ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to hide a row in table which has some content. I'm facing few issues..

1) After the height is set to 0 the border still shows up. How do I hide the whole div ?

2) Since there is colspan="5" for the content when it's hidden the table width shrinks

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td class="item0">test td 1</td>
    <td class="item1">test td 2</td>
    <td class="item2">test td 3</td>
    <td class="item3">test td 4</td>
    <td class="item4">Click for content</td>     
</tr>
<tr>
    <td  colspan="5">
        <div ng-hide="show" class="cssSlideUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar nisi sit amet luctus efficitur. Vivamus eu risus suscipit, ultricies tortor eu, sodales tellus. Sed sed feugiat massa. Cras mollis, erat eget pellentesque porttitor, mauris lectus ultricies neque, varius iaculis quam mi et quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc egestas nec mi eu lobortis. Nam eu scelerisque orci. Mauris vel ultricies dui, non accumsan turpis. Aliquam pulvinar in dolor sit amet fringilla. Integer sed quam pellentesque, volutpat arcu a, feugiat nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed auctor ac nulla sit amet suscipit.
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="item0">test td 5</td>
    <td class="item1">test td 6</td>
    <td class="item2">test td 7</td>
    <td class="item3">test td 8</td>
    <td class="item4">Click for content</td>     
</tr>
</table>
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/4ovuZ7YwOB3i8bK7WLLz?p=preview

Comment: You are hiding the whole div. The problem is that you've set your border on the <td>. That is the parent element of the div you're hiding, which is why the border remains. Add this to your css table{width:100%;} if you want the table to always be set to the full page width.

Comment: Is it possible to show/hide td or tr instead of div

Comment: Yes - just move the ng-hide="show" up to the <tr> level.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the whole div.

The problem is that you've set your border on the td. That is the parent element of the div you're hiding, which is why the border remains.

If you want the table to always have the same width, then you'll need to set its width. E.g. Add this to your css:

```
table{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the div, the table shrinks because it isn't set to have a width.  Therefore, it shrinks to only be the size it needs to be to display the remaining content.

Try adding a style to your CSS for the table to force it to always be a specific width, regardless of the content:

```
table { width: 100%; }
```

or...

```
<table width="100%">
```

As for the border issue, move you ng-hide to the 'tr':

```
<tr ng-hide="show">
    <td  colspan="5">
        <div class="cssSlideUp">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar nisi sit amet luctus efficitur. Vivamus eu risus suscipit, ultricies tortor eu, sodales tellus. Sed sed feugiat massa. Cras mollis, erat eget pellentesque porttitor, mauris lectus ultricies neque, varius iaculis quam mi et quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc egestas nec mi eu lobortis. Nam eu scelerisque orci. Mauris vel ultricies dui, non accumsan turpis. Aliquam pulvinar in dolor sit amet fringilla. Integer sed quam pellentesque, volutpat arcu a, feugiat nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed auctor ac nulla sit amet suscipit.
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```